# Querying two tables with one query with replacing word

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mySql like:

**table 1:** city

```
id    name     transport
1   new-york     1,3,4
2   dallas       3,4
3   la           1,2,4
4   california   3,4
```

**table 2:** transport

```
id     name
1   bus
2   trolleybus
3   train
4   metro
```

Can I received result like example with one query?

**result:**

```
id    name         transport
1   new-york     bus,train,metro
2   dallas       train,metro
3   la           bus,trolleybus,metro
4   california   train,metro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your database structure and normalize it. Never store data as comma-separation since its a bad way to store data. However till you fix the database design the following query should do what you are looking at.

```
select 
id,
name,
group_concat(transport)
from
(
  select
  c.id,
  c.name,
  t.transport as transport
  from city c
  join transport t on find_in_set(t.id,c.transport)

)x

group by id ;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfbd8/2)**

If you need to order the transport values then you can use

```
group_concat(transport ORDER BY transport)
```

**why is comma-separation is bad practice?**
You can read the following why it should be ignored
[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

To normalize the database you will need to create another table as

```
city_transport (cid int , tid) ;
cid = city id 
tid = transport id
```

For each city you will have multiple entry in this table. So the tables should look like

```
create table city (id int , name varchar(100));
insert into city values
(1,'new-york'),(2,'dallas'),(3,'la'),(4,'california');

create table transport (id int ,transport varchar(100));
insert into transport values
(1,'bus'),(2,'trolleybus'),(3,'train'),(4,'metro');

create table city_transport (cid int ,tid int);

insert into city_transport values
(1,1),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,4),(4,3),(4,4);
```

And the query to get the same result is as

```
select
c.id,
c.name,
group_concat(t.transport order by t.transport) as transport
from city_transport ct
join city c on c.id = ct.cid
join transport t on t.id = ct.tid 
group by c.id ;
```

When you have a large amount of data then essentially you will need index and then using join on indexed columns the performance will be way better than using find_in_set with comma separated list

Comment: Thanx, why is comma-separation is bad practice? what u can recommend
??

Answer (score 0):

You should work with a table between city and transport to be correct. That being said, you could fix this using [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) and [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html) but the performance will be horrible.